# How to empty an existing JSON array object without marshalling the entire document

Tags: json, go

I'm trying to import a large JSON document from a file, empty all arrays matching a specific key or pattern, then output it, without having to marshall the entire document.

It will be run as part of a periodic batch job, so performance/efficiency is not a priority.

Simplicity, and making sure the code is agnostic to the overall JSON structure, is more important.

Is there an easy way to do solve this in Go?

Example input:

```
{
  "panels": [
    {
      "alert": {
        "executionErrorState": "alerting",
        "notifications": [
          {
            "uid": "fRLbH_6Zk"
          },
          {
            "uid": "8gamKl6Waz"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "alert": {
        "executionErrorState": "alerting",
        "notifications": [
          {
            "uid": "DqjrD_6Zk"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Desired output (all entries in 'alert.notifications' in 'panels' removed):

```
{
  "panels": [
    {
      "alert": {
        "executionErrorState": "alerting",
        "notifications": []
      }
    },
    {
      "alert": {
        "executionErrorState": "alerting",
        "notifications": []
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Doing this correctly will end up looking like a custom implementation of unmarshaling. You are much better off unmarshaling, clearing the fields, and marshaling. Especially in terms of correctness and simplicity.

Comment: Without fully unmarshaling and then marshaling the json this is not possible with the standard `encoding/json` package.

Comment: Why not use something like jq if you don't actually want the rest of trhe data? https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: Try considering `sed` as an option. If you can make a regular expression then you can simply run a `sed` command periodically instead of writing this whole thing in Go.

Comment: To avoid ending up with a custom implementation of unmarshaling in Go, I decided to go with jq. Syntax: `jq 'del(.panels[].alert.notifications) | .panels[].alert.notifications=[]' file.json`. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

you can use read streams, to read objects one by one. Code will be unmarshall first object, but will have error on the next one. Its like approve of state that code dont read whole file, here example:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    const jsonStream = `
    [
        {"Name": "Ed", "Text": "Knock knock."},
        asdasd sadasd,
`
    type Message struct {
        Name, Text string
    }
    dec := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(jsonStream))

    // read open bracket
    t, err := dec.Token()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%T: %v\n", t, t)

    // while the array contains values
    for dec.More() {
        var m Message
        // decode an array value (Message)
        err := dec.Decode(&m)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        fmt.Printf("%v: %v\n", m.Name, m.Text)
    }

    // read closing bracket
    t, err = dec.Token()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%T: %v\n", t, t)

}
```